# Auto-comment new line in Vim only for block comments

Tags: vim, comments, autoformatting

When I start a new line at the end of a single-line comment in a `.{cpp,h}` file, `vim` is automatically commenting it. For example:

```
// This is a comment<CR>
// | <- Cursor is moved to `|`, `//` is automatically inserted.
```

I'm not sure if this is a plugin or a setting. I can't see anything that looks like it'd do this in my `~/.vimrc`, and the loaded plugins are listed below.

I *like* this for `/* */`-style *multiline* comments, but I don't want my *single-line* comments running over multiple lines by default.

Which setting (or plugin) does this, and can I turn it off *for this comment type only*?

`:scriptnames` gives this:

```
  1: /Users/simont/.vimrc
  2: /usr/local/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syntax.vim
  3: /usr/local/share/vim/vim73/syntax/synload.vim
  4: /usr/local/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syncolor.vim
  5: /usr/local/share/vim/vim73/filetype.vim
  6: /usr/local/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin.vim
  7: /usr/local/share/vim/vim73/syntax/nosyntax.vim
  8: /Users/simont/repositories/config-files/vim/colors/solarized.vim
  9: /usr/local/share/vim/vim73/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 10: /usr/local/share/vim/vim73/plugin/gzip.vim
 11: /usr/local/share/vim/vim73/plugin/matchparen.vim
 12: /usr/local/share/vim/vim73/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 13: /usr/local/share/vim/vim73/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 14: /usr/local/share/vim/vim73/plugin/spellfile.vim
 15: /usr/local/share/vim/vim73/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 16: /usr/local/share/vim/vim73/plugin/tohtml.vim
 17: /usr/local/share/vim/vim73/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 18: /usr/local/share/vim/vim73/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 19: /usr/local/share/vim/vim73/scripts.vim
 20: /usr/local/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/vim.vim
 21: /usr/local/share/vim/vim73/syntax/vim.vim
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
au FileType c,cpp setlocal comments-=:// comments+=f://
```

In your vimrc should do the trick for `//` without affecting block comments, in {cpp,h} files.

To try it temporarily in the current buffer use:

```
:setlocal comments-=:// comments+=f://
```

Comment: What does `comments+=f://` do?

Answer (score 6):

This kind of configuration, that is related to specific file types, are normally set through a file-type plugin. There is a number of file-types for common filetypes (such as `.cpp`) that comes with Vim. You can check the file-type for a buffer with `:set ft?`.

The setting for continue comments after you start a new line comes from option `'comments'`, as pb2q said.
For `.{cpp,h}` the default file-type is 'cpp', and the `'comment'` option is set at `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/c.vim`, as the `cpp.vim` is in the same directory. From the `c.vim` file:

```
  " Set 'comments' to format dashed lists in comments.
  setlocal comments=sO:*\ -,mO:*\ \ ,exO:*/,s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://
```

The `comments` option is a list of `{flags}:{string}`, and flags `f`and `O` avoid extending the comment new lines.

From the [Vim FAQ](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-26.6):

```
  You can use an autocommand triggered on the FileType event:

      au Filetype * set formatoptions=xyz

  This should at least be after "filetype on" in your vimrc. Best is to put
  it in your "myfiletypefile" file, so that it's always last.


  If you want to override a setting for a particular filetype, then create a
  file with the same name as the original filetype plugin in the
  ~/.vim/after/ftplugin directory For example, to override a setting in the
  c.vim filetype plugin, create a c.vim file in the ~/.vim/after/ftplugin
  directory and add your preferences in this file.
```

So create the file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim` with

```
  setlocal comments-=://
  setlocal comments+=fO://
```

should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an autocommand triggered on the FileType event:

```
  au Filetype * set formatoptions=xyz
```

This should at least be after "filetype on" in your vimrc. Best is to put
  it in your "myfiletypefile" file, so that it's always last.

If you want to override a setting for a particular filetype, then create a
  file with the same name as the original filetype plugin in the
  ~/.vim/after/ftplugin directory For example, to override a setting in the
  c.vim filetype plugin, create a c.vim file in the ~/.vim/after/ftplugin
  directory and add your preferences in this file.
So create the file ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim with

setlocal comments-=://
  setlocal comments+=fO://